# Listing the user privilèges in a specific folder alfresco cmis java

Tags: java, alfresco, user-roles, cmis

I want to know if there is any java method or any topics about how to know user role on a specific folder (Consumer, Contributor, Collaborator...)

For my project I use differentes methods, for example: uploadfile, create folder ...

Now I want to improve a user management, so if the user has the role consumer he can't delete a file.
Any solution for this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do this. One is to ask the folder for its ACL by calling getACL(), see the [docs](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.13.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/CmisObject.html#getAcl%28%29).

Another option would be to ask the folder for its allowable actions by calling getAllowableActions(), see the [docs](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.13.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/CmisObject.html#getAllowableActions%28%29). This one might be better because it will return given the context of the current user. If the getAllowableActions() call does not return "CAN_DELETE_OBJECT" then you know the current user is not allowed to delete the object.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you know any method to Copy/Paste a document in Alfresco using CMIS (and a Folder)

Comment: @KamelJahloug Please start a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look to this maybe it can help to solve your problem

http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/04/28/3703